# How to use two ORM in same project [Play Framework]

Tags: orm, cassandra, ebean, playframework-2.3, kundera

I am using Play framework. Can I use two ORM in the same project?
I am already using Ebean and now want to use Kundera for a Cassandra purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As long as Kundera is concerned, it refers JPA libraries and doesn't override any. You may want to cross check for EBean.
If that's ok then good to use both of them.